# How to count instace of Mat class from EmguCV?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to trace the count of Mat instance, add 1 if constructor been invoked and minus 1 if it's been disposed, to avoid memory leak.

Is it possible with extension method or insert some trigger to Mat?
Or I have to wrap every call to the contructor and dispose method?

```
int count;

Mat result = new Mat();
count++;
...
result.Dispose();
count--;
```